# Did Jesus bear his own cross?

Tags: john, matthew, contradiction

Did Jesus bear his own cross? John and Matthew seem to disagree:

> John 19:17 Carrying his own cross, he went out to the place of the Skull (which in Aramaic is called Golgotha).
>
> Matthew 27:32: As they were going out, they met a man from Cyrene, named Simon, and they forced him to carry the cross.

Comment: "I loaded my grocery bags and went out of the store". "As I went out, my son met me and  took the bags." — How do those statements contradict each other?

Answer (score 7):

Not only in Matthew does Simon of Cyrene carry the cross; also in Mark (15:21) and Luke (23:26). I have always interpreted this as Jesus starting to carry his own cross from Pilate's place until he couldn't bear it anymore (or went too slow for the soldiers), at which point they met Simon of Cyrene who brought the cross to its final destination. John simply omits this as he deemed it not important enough for his book, just like other parts are left out in other gospels.

So in all four gospels, Jesus bore his own cross.

Comment: you should say , yes or no and show why this corruption were made ? and thanks

Comment: According to your claim ,Then the Matthew version should be through out since it says no ?

Comment: Matthew says "As they were coming out" - out of what? The palace? The city? Enough time before for Jesus to bear his own cross alone, and 32b does not say they weren't carrying it together.

Comment: I think I have referenced the second answer of mathew as well and the answer was " no" try to check again Matthew 27:31-32 ? or is it changed again ?

Comment: @Glorfindel -  Excellent answer.  The Gospel writers did not include everything but only what they were inspired to include. (+1)

Comment: Excellent answer in trick and corruption

Comment: @MohamedSalim He 'went out' carrying his own cross, as John tells us. But on the way something happened, which John does not narrate, but Matthew, Mark and Luke do. No trickery. No corruption. No problem.